# Combine two TTS outputs in a single mp3 file not working

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want to combine two requests to the Google cloud text-to-speech API in a single mp3 output. The reason I need to combine two requests is that the output should contain two different languages.

Below code works fine for many language pair combinations, but unfortunately not for all. If I request e.g. a sentence in English and one in German and combine them everything works. If I request one in English and one in Japanes I can't combine the two files in a single output. The output only contains the first sentence and instead of the second sentence, it outputs silence.

I tried now multiple ways to combine the two outputs but the result stays the same. The code below should show the issue.

Please run the code first with:
python synthesize_bug.py --t1 'Hallo' --code1 de-De --t2 'August' --code2 de-De 
This works perfectly.

python synthesize_bug.py --t1 'Hallo' --code1 de-De --t2 'こんにちは' --code2 ja-JP
This doesn't work. The single files are ok, but the combined files contain silence instead of the Japanese part.
Also, if used with two Japanes sentences everything works.

I already filed a bug report at Google with no response yet, but maybe it's just me who is doing something wrong here with encoding assumptions. Hope someone has an idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

# [START tts_synthesize_text_file]
def synthesize_text_file(text1, text2, code1, code2):
    """Synthesizes speech from the input file of text."""
    from apiclient.discovery import build
    import base64

    service = build('texttospeech', 'v1beta1')
    collection = service.text()

    data1 = {}
    data1['input'] = {}
    data1['input']['ssml'] = '<speak><break time="2s"/></speak>'
    data1['voice'] = {}
    data1['voice']['ssmlGender'] = 'FEMALE'
    data1['voice']['languageCode'] = code1
    data1['audioConfig'] = {}
    data1['audioConfig']['speakingRate'] = 0.8
    data1['audioConfig']['audioEncoding'] = 'MP3'

    request = collection.synthesize(body=data1)
    response = request.execute() 
    audio_pause = base64.b64decode(response['audioContent'].decode('UTF-8'))
    raw_pause = response['audioContent']

    ssmlLine = '<speak>' + text1 + '</speak>' 

    data1 = {}
    data1['input'] = {}
    data1['input']['ssml'] = ssmlLine
    data1['voice'] = {}
    data1['voice']['ssmlGender'] = 'FEMALE'
    data1['voice']['languageCode'] = code1
    data1['audioConfig'] = {}
    data1['audioConfig']['speakingRate'] = 0.8
    data1['audioConfig']['audioEncoding'] = 'MP3'

    request = collection.synthesize(body=data1)
    response = request.execute() 

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output1.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(base64.b64decode(response['audioContent'].decode('UTF-8')))
        print('Audio content written to file "output1.mp3"')

        audio_text1 = base64.b64decode(response['audioContent'].decode('UTF-8'))
        raw_text1 = response['audioContent']

    ssmlLine = '<speak>' + text2 + '</speak>' 

    data2 = {}
    data2['input'] = {}
    data2['input']['ssml'] = ssmlLine
    data2['voice'] = {}
    data2['voice']['ssmlGender'] = 'MALE'
    data2['voice']['languageCode'] = code2 #'ko-KR'
    data2['audioConfig'] = {}
    data2['audioConfig']['speakingRate'] = 0.8
    data2['audioConfig']['audioEncoding'] = 'MP3'

    request = collection.synthesize(body=data2)
    response = request.execute() 

    # The response's audio_content is binary.
    with open('output2.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(base64.b64decode(response['audioContent'].decode('UTF-8')))
        print('Audio content written to file "output2.mp3"')

    audio_text2 = base64.b64decode(response['audioContent'].decode('UTF-8'))
    raw_text2 = response['audioContent']

    result = audio_text1 + audio_pause + audio_text2
    with open('result.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(result)
    print('Audio content written to file "result.mp3"')

    raw_result = raw_text1 + raw_pause + raw_text2
    with open('raw_result.mp3', 'wb') as out:
        out.write(base64.b64decode(raw_result.decode('UTF-8')))
    print('Audio content written to file "raw_result.mp3"')
# [END tts_synthesize_text_file]ls



if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('--t1')
    parser.add_argument('--code1')
    parser.add_argument('--t2')
    parser.add_argument('--code2')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    synthesize_text_file(args.t1, args.t2, args.code1, args.code2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer here: 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120687867

Short answer: It's not clear why it is not working, but Google suggests a workaround to first write the files as .wav, combine and then re-encode the result to mp3.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this in NodeJS with just one function (idk how optimal is it, but at least it works). Maybe you could take inspiration from it
I have used memory-streams dependency from npm

```
var streams = require('memory-streams');
function mergeAudios(audios) {
  var reader = new streams.ReadableStream();
  var writer = new streams.WritableStream();
  audios.forEach(element => {
    if (element instanceof streams.ReadableStream) {
      element.pipe(writer)
    }
    else {
      writer.write(element)
    }
  });
  reader.append(writer.toBuffer())
  return reader
}
```

Input parameter is a list which contain ReadableStream or responce.audioContent from synthesizeSpeech operation. If it is readablestream, it uses pipe operation, if it is audiocontent, it uses write method. At the end all content is passed into an readabblestream.